# Lagrange multipliers subject to a 3-variable, 4th degree constraint function?

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I have recently been tackling the following problem:

If $a+b+c = 0 $ and $ a^2 + b^2 +c^2 = 1$, work out $a^4 +b^4 +c^4$.

Could this problem admit a solution through the method of lagrange multipliers. Is my thinking  in that the maximum and minimum are the same, and thus the method is valid, correct or flawed? If the latter is true, could you please point out the error in my reasoning, otherwise show how to carry out the method, with full working. I have already solved the problem using nothing more than basic algebraic manipulation, but it would be interesting to see if this method works.

Comment: There is a neat way to do this by letting $a,b,c$ be the three roots of a cubic polynomial - which may be your algebraic manipulation method, and is probably equivalent to it.

Comment: My method is just manipulating the constraints to find out neww values, such as $ab+bc+ac= -\frac{1}{2}$ and so on, and just finding the values of expressions. As for this being equivalent, I am not sure I fully understand your method. Could you elaborate please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just for info (see comments), let $a,b,c$ be the roots of a cubic polynomial.

Since $a+b+c=0$ this has form $x^3+px+q=0$ where $$p=ab+bc+ca=\cfrac {(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}2=-\cfrac 12$$

Now note multiply by $x$ to see that $a,b,c$ satisfy $f(x)=x^4+px^2+qx=0$

Then $$0=f(a)+f(b)+f(c)=(a^4+b^4+c^4)+p(a^2+b^2+c^2)+q(a+b+c)$$

Substituting known values gives $a^4+b^4+c^4=\cfrac 12$

Working with polynomials is sometimes a convenient way of capturing and organising information about symmetric functions.

Comment: Nice, I was thinking about Newton's identity.

Comment: Thanks. On an irrelevant side note, it seems that on the few occasions when I pose a question on stackexchange, you are always the one that helps me. Thanks a lot