Prove/disprove that $a^{2m} + b^{2m} + c^{2m} > 2^{1-m}$ subject to $a + b + c= 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$

Problem. Let $a, b, c$ be reals with $abc\ne 0$, $a + b + c = 0$, and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$. Prove or disprove that
$a^{2m} + b^{2m} + c^{2m} > 2^{1-m}, \forall m\in \mathbb{Z}_{>2}$.

Prior thoughts.

I saw a post here, where it was proved that if $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ then $a^4+b^4+c^4=1/2$. I was going to add a comment to that post but cannot find it now and the search function was no help or yielded too many choices, so I am creating a new post here.
Trivially, if $abc=0$, $a + b + c = 0$, and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, then equality holds: $a^{2m} + b^{2m} + c^{2m}= 2^{1-m},\forall m>0$.
I am not 100 percent sure of the inequality in the problem above, but it seems so, at least from trials.


If the two first equalities imply the third one, why do you assume redundantly  the latter?

The OP is clearly a beginner but he has been edited by a high reputed member of MSE. We can prove (it is not hard) that the two first equations  imply LHS of the third one is identically equal to $\frac12$ whatever be  $a_1,a_2,a_3$.

@Piquito yes that was proved already in that post i could not find. The edit of the person who did it is the question. that is to prove the inequality assuming it is true and if not true an example which violates it

Again:  the two first equalities imply the third one, which is therefore redundant ($a_i$ are the roots of $X^3-\frac X2-P$ where $P$ is their product, hence $\sum a_i^4=\sum(\frac{a_i^2}2+Pa_i)=\frac12$).

@Anne Bauval I knew it was redundant in the first place because it had been proved prior but helps to state it again. Anyway i can't understand how you get $a_i$ are the roots of $X^3-X/2-P$ where are u getting that and the statement $\sum(a_i^2/2+Pa_i)=1/2$ makes no sense either. Neither does the statement that it equals $\sum a_i^4$ make any sense either.

$a_i$
are the roots of $X3−X/2−P$ comes from Vieta's formulas and the fact that $0=(\sum a_i)^2=1+2\sum_{i<j}a_ia_j$. Then, $\sum(a_i^2/2+Pa_i)=\frac12\sum a_i^2+P\sum a_i=\frac12\cdot1+P\cdot0.$ Finally, $a_i^4=a_i\cdot a_i^3=a_i(a_i/2+P)$. If you knew it was redundant, then again: why add this third equality in the hypothesis, instead (if you insist on mentionning this 3rd one) of stating explicitly that it is a consequence of the 1st and 2nd?

Here is one problem of the type you are after: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588553/find-the-value-of-a4b4c4 Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325068/if-abc-4-a2b2c2-7-a3b3c3-28-find-a4b4c4-and-a5b5c and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305143/what-is-the-value-of-a4b4c4 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967042/lagrange-multipliers-subject-to-a-3-variable-4th-degree-constraint-function and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960256/if-a2-b2-c2-4-and-a3-b3-c3-8-then-find-a4b4c4

We have the identity
$$a^4 + b^4 + c^4$$
$$= \frac12
\left( {a}^{2}+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2} \right) ^{2}-\frac12\left( a+b+c \right) ^{4}+ \left( a+b+c \right) ^{2} \left( {a}
^{2}+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2} \right) +4, \left( a+b+c \right) abc$$
$$= \frac12$$

since $a,b,c$ satisfy the cubic $x^3-x/2+P=0$ with discriminant $1/8-27P^2$ the condition that the roots are all real is $|P| \le (216)^{-1/2}$ while for example $a^6+b^6+c^6=1/4-P(a^3+b^3+c^3)=1/4+P^2 \ge 1/4$ and probably some inductive argument can be cobbled for the following powers

@Anne Bauval Think u made a couple errors in your explaining post. Where u put X3 after 'roots of' should it not have been X^3.And did you not leave off summation symbols in that last expression after 'Finally,' ?

No error at all. An obvious typo indeed, that's all: $X3$ meant of course $X^3$ (no doubt about it since I was answering your "how you get $a_i$
are the roots of $X^3−X/2−P$", quoting my "$a_i$ are the roots of $X^3-\frac X2-P$"), My "leave off summation symbols" was on purpose, to help you understand the first step (after that, doing the summation is a formality). If the redundancy is now clear to you, again: please either mention it explicitely in your post, or wipe off the 3rd condition, to make things clearer for future readers.

redundancy was clear to me before i posted it in the first place as it was proved by a different method already in that prior post to which i was referring but could not find now as i stated.

Well then, again, for the benefit of future readers, please clarify your post: replace "I saw a post here that went something like..." by (for instance) "I saw a post here were it was proved that..."), and suppress from your question the 3rd hypothesis  (which will then become explicitely redundant). If the post you saw was one of those mentionned by Gerry, you could also insert the link.

By Bernoulli inequality $(1 + u)^r \ge 1 + ur$ for all $u > -1$ and $r \ge 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &2^{m-1} (a^{2m} + b^{2m} + c^{2m})\\
 ={}& a^2 (2a^2)^{m-1} + b^2(2b^2)^{m-1} + c^2(2c^2)^{m-1}\\
 \ge{}& a^2 [1 + (2a^2 - 1)(m-1)] + b^2[1 + (2b^2 - 1)(m-1)]\\
 &\qquad
 + c^2 [1 + (2c^2 - 1)(m - 1)]\\
 ={}& a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + (2a^4 + 2b^4 + 2c^4 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2)(m-1)\\
 ={}& 1
\end{align*}
where we use the fact that $a + b + c = 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$ imply
$2a^4 + 2b^4 + 2c^4 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2 = 0$.
Also, if $abc \ne 0$, the equality does not occur.

Hi my friend. Can you give me some documents on the application of Padé approximants.

I have seen you use this method before.

That's exactly what I want, the documents on the internet are not as good as your proof.

Please @nguyenhuyenag, delete your comments.

think now i do see that post of $a^4+b^4+c^4=1/2$ to which i was referring and said could not find. It's the first two under linked ' what is the value of $a^4+b^4+c^4$ ' and 'find the value....'

@user158293 As you see, it is easy to prove $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = 1/2$ by various methods. You can prove it yourself when you post your question.

the reason why it works for 3 variables a,b,c or call them $a_i , i,1..n$ for $n=3$ or less is because in the sense of symmetric polynomial identities, newton's identities, etc. is because one can analyze all the terms given in the answer to $\sum_{i=1} ^n a_i^4 $ in terms of other symmetric functions is in general for $n>3$ there would be another symmetric function involved which is sum of products $a_i a_j a_k a_l$ for $0<i<j<k<l<n+1$ which is absent when $n<4$

I did not modify my original question since it had already been done prior by others, the so called redundant equation was already shown to be a consequence of the other 2 more than once and that would have already known by anyone reading it.. When anyone reads it they are going to read the modification , bold part at top ,  not much of my original and i did not even know if i could or how to modify it again. Also i now see an error of the bold part in beginning $a^{2m}+b^{2m}+c^{2m}>2^{1-m}$ should have used $\geq$ instead of > or else added condition $abc\ne 0$

Most all those who have edited original question have left off the requirement $m>2$ in the inequality.
$\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i^{2m} >2^{1-m}, \prod_{i=1}^3 a_i \ne 0$  is only true for $m>2$.
It may likely be the case for $m>2$ that with respect to symmetric fct's there are identities for $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i^{2m}$ which contain
positive definite terms containing $(a_1 a_2 a_3)^2$ as a factor which are necessarily absent for $m=2$
